# Ubuntu 14.04 keyboard light not working

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, wireless-keyboards

I created a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to test some command that I need to learn in my classes. But my Keyboard light isn't turning on, the key to turn them on is SCR LK on windows. But it is not working on Ubuntu, I tried many tutorials on YouTube also here in Ask Ubuntu. Anyone have a solution please?
Also, this is my keyboard for more info: http://gaming.coolermaster.com/en/products/keyboards/devastator/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried from a terminal with a command to turn the backlight on and off?  The commands would be `xset led 3` to turn it on, and  `xset -led 3` to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks Terrance ! after installing VMware tools and entring this command, it worked. thank you !

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad it's working for you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Type this in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to turn on the backlight of your keyboard:

```
xset led on
```

to disable it type:

```
xset led off
```

Hope this works for you. It worked for me.